# What is the Catholic view on EFT?

Tags: catholicism, other-religions

Did the Catholic Church or any of the representatives issued any stance on [Emotional Freedom Technique](http://eft.mercola.com/) (EFT)?

I realize it comes from an Eastern religion which is not in line with Christianity, but my question is: what would be wrong with a simple tapping. How can evil spirits enter our life through the tapping on our body?

What is the danger? Instead of understanding and accepting the cross we get from a physical pain, we lean to tapping?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Catholics should be wary of the acceptance of eastern, non-Christian religious concepts. EFT appears to have similarities with acupuncture, so I did some looking for acupuncture since EFT is lesser-known. I came across the following:

> The Western form of acupuncture, which is based on science and not
> Taoism, is acceptable for use by Christians. However, the traditional
> Chinese acupuncture belief system is not compatible with Christianity.
>
> "The philosophical thinking behind acupuncture comes from Taoism and
> the concept of the yin and yang, and of being at one with the forces
> in the universe through meditation," the Irish Theological Commission
> wrote in 1994 in its document, "A Catholic Response to the New Age
> Phenomenon." ([See article](http://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/view.cfm?recnum=8758))

So the test for whether this practice conflicts with Catholicism is whether it incorporates foreign teachings that conflict with core beliefs within the faith.

If something helps with pain or addiction and has been stripped of the dangerous dogmas of another faith, it may be harmless. This seems to rely somewhat on a placebo effect. Placebo effects can actually be very powerful at overcoming pain, apprehension, and addiction ([see further reading](https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/s/ref=is_s?k=the%20placebo%20effect))

A word of warning: recognize that these activities have the potential to soften your objectivity when encountering elements from eastern religions like Taoism. It has the potential to inadvertently open you up to oppositional ideas and concepts that could lead you into dangerous territory.

Answer (score -1):

There’s no religious forms of scientific treatment. Western medicine and Eastern medicine are simply named according to their culture of origin. Both are biologically based. 
In fact Eastern medicine supersedes our medicines by almost 2000 years. In many Asian countries, national insurances cover both forms of medicine equally. It also takes more years of study to become an Eastern Medical Dr.  than Western Medical Dr.

There are Catholics in China who’ve had and continue to use their own medical system because it’s natural to them.

It’s one thing to prefer a medical form treatment and another to denigrate another because it isn’t like yours.

EFT does work. Anyone with crippling anxiety or panic attacks will benefit from it and those who’ve gone through trauma and experienced it can attest to it. I certainly can.

Old age isn’t always beneficial and New age, isn’t always demonic or useless. Stay open. Trust your intuition. Research all available documents: Scientific, Spiritual or Experiential.

The world and the wisdom in it is vast and endless...

Comment: It is not true that there is no such thing as religious treatment. Some treatments are absolutely based on religious principles and not scientific.

Comment: Absolutely agree. DJ. My mother works for a Christian clinic that uses herbal remedies. But there are some bizarre techniques that other people use that are directly tied to Hinduism, Eastern religion and New Age such as healing crystals and hypnosis.